# Jquery ajax request not working in IE?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, debugging, internet-explorer

I'm experiencing a strange problem in IE with an ajax request. It works fine in FF and Chrome, but for some reason no data is added to the resultsPage, slideInResults is called, and the empty page appears. Inspecting it I can see there is nothing there. What can I do to fix this?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "library/ajax/search.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html){
            $('#resultsPage').html(html);
            slideInResults();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all tag and case of variables. They creates problem in IE if not properly close or in different case.

Comment: that's what it was...a stray tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to verify if the request is being sent. If it is, verify that the values sent are correct and finally, verify that the PHP page is not returning a bad response.

Comment: cheers for the link - looks useful. I'm pretty sure everything is fine on that side of things though, as even if there was a bad response I should be able to see that rendered on the results page

Answer (score 0):

Report the response of the PHP page by using an Alert. This will assist with you identifying the source of the issue.

Comment: Yes the correct data is received, even if they were errors they should still be appended though. $('#resultsPage').replaceWith(html); has no impact either